# UISplitViewController changes display mode when app suspends

Tags: ios, uikit, uisplitviewcontroller

I noticed some bizarre behavior in my iPad app: when the app transitions to the background, my active view controller receives `viewWillAppear`/`viewDidAppear` messages.

From my investigation, it seems this is happening because when my app moves to the background, my `UISplitViewController` for some reason first transitions its display mode to `.PrimaryHidden` and then immediately back to what it was before (`.AllVisible`).

Is this expected behavior? If so, why does `UISplitViewController` need to change its display mode (twice) when the app suspends, and is there a way to prevent it from doing so?

Edit: I just verified this behavior with a simple test app, but I'm no closer to understanding why it happens or how to prevent it.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm getting the same behavior.  To further complicate matters, when the app is foregrounded viewWillAppear does not get called, giving me no indication the view has been presented to the user.

Comment: Same here in iOS 13 2020